# Trouble viewing iPod in Rhythmbox

Tags: ubuntu, mount, rhythmbox

Once in a blue moon, my ipod (160 GB) will show up in rhythmbox on my ubuntu 12.04 laptop when I plug it it, but most of the time nothing happens.

It shows up when I do `fdisk -l`, but when I try to mount it by `sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /media/ipod`, where `sdd1` reflects the output of `fdisk`, and where `/media/ipod` is a directory I created, mount says that either it is already mounted, or that the directory is busy.

Doing `sudo umount /dev/sdd1` gives that the device is not mounted. But doing `sudo /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sde1 /media/ipod` gives that it is mounted. I am also able to see that the device is connected by doing `sudo blkid`. Asking rhythmbox to 'search for new devices' appears to have no effect.

Comment: I thought it might have to do with some ipod disk-use setting, but it shows up properly on my laptop running crouton (but unfortunately that's not where my music is!)